# How can I declare many of classes in one line on my Controller?

Tags: laravel-5.7

I would declare them with the star * on MyController

```html
use App\Client;
use App\Cabinet;
use App\Giac;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `*` wildcard with PHP namespace imports. But if you really need an **one-liner**, you could group them like this:

```
use App\{Client, Cabinet, Giac};
```